# Add space between list elements without modifying CSS in the header? (and without adding CSS to each <li> element)

Tags: html, css

I'm working in a content management system (Confluence) where I don't have the ability to declare CSS stuff in the HTML header.

It looks like the old <style></style> attribute is deprecated.   Is there anyway to make a style declaration in the list tag (<ul> or <ol>) that adds spacing to each <li> element in that list?  (like 'cellspacing' or 'cellpadding' attributes in a <table> declaration)

Comment: using a separate css stylesheet?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: `<style></style>` is deprecated? What makes you think that?

Answer (score 0):

You must include link or style to get class styles.

If style tag is disabled, upload css and add that file url in href

```
<link href="list.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

// Add below code in list.css
ul.space-list li {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

<!-- html -->
<ul class="space-list">
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Or, you can go with old school method `<br/>` tag as well like below

```
<!-- html -->
<ul class="space-list">
<li>Lorem ipsum</li> <br/><br/>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li> <br/><br/>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```